# SQL subquery in INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, subquery

Is it possible to use a subquery in an INSERT statement?

```
INSERT INTO table (age, p_id) 
VALUES('22', '(SELECT id FROM people WHERE name='Bob')')
```

Is there a working form of what I'm attempting?

Using MySQL database

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: you should use a select instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (age, p_id)
SELECT '22', ( select id from people where name = 'bob')
```

or you could do this

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (age, p_id)
SELECT '22', id 
FROM people
WHERE name = 'bob'
```

Comment: There's no need for the subquery.  `INSERT INTO MyTable (age, p_id) SELECT '22', id FROM people WHERE name = 'bob'`  The literal value `22` can just go into the select list.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I agree

Comment: I know there was no need for subquery, I was trying to use the same strucure used in the persons question to make it easier for them to follow.

Comment: that is going to show the OP bad Syntax.  better to show them good structure.

Comment: That second method is much more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

should be something like

```
INSERT INTO table (age, p_id)
SELECT '22', people.id
    FROM people
    WHERE people.name = 'bob
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table (age, p_id) 
SELECT '22', (SELECT id FROM people WHERE name='Bob'))
```

or better...

```
INSERT INTO table (age, p_id) 
SELECT '22',id FROM people WHERE name='Bob'
```